# How to place text between two `<i>` in HTML?

Tags: html, css

So the title is not the best but I'm actually trying to modify the `font-size` of this text:

```
<i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>Containers graphics<i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

I have tried to put `<p> Containers graphics </p>` but then the icons where one upside and one downside the text...

Thank you for your help and ideas

Comment: Maybe you should put your text in span and then add some styles to it to change font size?

Comment: Try `<span> Containers graphics </span>`

Comment: For example `<span style="font-size:15px">Text</span>`

Comment: Anyway our solution (putting text into span) is better than changing the whole `a` display to inline.

Comment: So yes the solution of CrazyMatt and forexknight are the right ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place `<span` with `font-size`

```html
<i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i><span style="font-size:20px">Containers graphics</span><i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add display:inline to the css.

like that:

```
.fa{display:inline;} a{display:inline;}
```

Of course you better add classes specific to those elements so it wont effect every .fa and every a element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```css
.container {
  font-size: 20px;
 }

.container i {
  font-size: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true">Ico</i>Containers graphics<i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true">Ico</i>
</div>
```